# org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i have three servers to run zookeeper and kafka clusters. one day one of kafka app didn't open port 9092,and failed to restart. this is the error log:

```
[2022-06-30 11:50:42,459] INFO Opening socket connection to server nv54/192.168.**.**:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-06-30 11:50:42,463] INFO Socket connection established to nv54/192.168.**.**:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-06-30 11:50:42,469] INFO Session establishment complete on server nv54/192.168.179.54:2181, sessionid = 0x303a1d787d1000b, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-06-30 11:50:42,472] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2022-06-30 11:50:42,519] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /consumers
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:116)
    ...
```

server.properties:

```
broker.id=52
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.**.**:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/my_own_dir/data_kafka
num.partitions=1

……

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
zookeeper.connect=192.168.**.*1:2181,192.168.**.*2:2181,192.168.**.*3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
auto.create.topics.enable=true
delete.topic.enable=true
```

[getAcl /consumers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3bhp.png)

how to solve this error?

Comment: while one of the kafka nodes failed, i restart the rest of two alive kafka nodes, then both of them failed too , throw the same error....